# Temporal clustering in SQL

Tags: sql, presto, gaps-and-islands, trino

I have a list of timestamps that I'd like to cluster together. For example, given the following timestamps:

```
2022-01-02T03:04:00
2022-01-02T03:05:00
2023-04-05T06:07:00
2023-04-05T06:08:00
2023-04-05T06:10:00
```

I would like to return something like:

```
start                  end
2022-01-02T03:04:00    2022-01-02T03:05:00
2023-04-05T06:07:00    2023-04-05T06:10:00
```

Is this possible in modern SQL?

Comment: What is the rule here? Every day should be combined into separate row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that kind of analysis with `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`. For instance, if you want to group events that are within 1 day of each other in the same cluster, you could do this:

```
WITH data(t) AS (
    VALUES
     TIMESTAMP '2022-01-02 03:04:00',
     TIMESTAMP '2022-01-02 03:05:00',
     TIMESTAMP '2023-04-05 06:07:00',
     TIMESTAMP '2023-04-05 06:08:00',
     TIMESTAMP '2023-04-05 06:10:00'
)
SELECT *
FROM data
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    ORDER BY t
    MEASURES
        FIRST(A.t) AS start_time,
        LAST(A.t) AS end_time
    ONE ROW PER MATCH
    AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
    PATTERN (A+)
    DEFINE
        A AS t - FIRST(t) < INTERVAL '1' DAY
)
```

You can adjust the `t - FIRST(t) < INTERVAL '1' DAY` if you want different criteria for grouping the entries.

See these for more details on how `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` works:

- https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/match-recognize.html
- https://trino.io/blog/2021/05/19/row_pattern_matching.html

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided sample you can just group by truncated to a day date:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(date) as (
    values ('2022-01-02T03:04:00'),
    ('2022-01-02T03:05:00'),
    ('2023-04-05T06:07:00'),
    ('2023-04-05T06:08:00'),
    ('2023-04-05T06:10:00')
)

-- query
select min(ts) start,
       max(ts) "end"
from (select from_iso8601_timestamp(date) as ts
    from dataset)
group by date_trunc('day', ts);
```

Output:

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02 03:04:00.000 UTC | 2022-01-02 03:05:00.000 UTC |
| 2023-04-05 06:07:00.000 UTC | 2023-04-05 06:10:00.000 UTC |